# How to Insert Data Field Table SQL Server from another SQL Server in different ip?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cron, sqlcmd

I need help to insert data from one IP to another IP of SQL Server.
I've tried using `sqlcmd` but it doesn't work as mysql syntax works on bash which can insert data using csv or txt file after manipulation of data with awk.

In this case there are 2 tables and 2 IP:

- Table A (field: A1,A2,A3,A4,A5) on IP 22
- Table B (field: B1,B2,B3,... , Bn) on IP 23
- I need to Insert data like this (A1 to B2)
- I need to run it with task scheduler or crontab

I hope someone can help me with this case.

Comment: Do you have access to SSIS? are you able to use the SQL Agent Scheduler?

Comment: is it sql server or mysql?

Comment: @BrianZ I can use SQL Agent Scheduler, but I don't know about SSIS. I searched for SSIS on my server and I didn't find it. Can you help me?

Comment: @VenkataramanR sql server

Comment: Are you using Sql server on windows or Linux?

Comment: @BrianZ my sql server is in windows, but I need to run scheduler on wsl because I need to run some operating data using bash scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a windows computer with Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) installed, you can use the Import Wizard (right click on the table -> tasks -> import data) to create an SSIS package that will copy the data from one server to another and save the package.
[Import and Export Data with the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you want to edit the package, you will need [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15).  You might not need to edit it.

Then you can create a SQL Agent Job to run the SSIS Package from the file system
[SQL Server Agent Jobs for Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-ver15)

Then you could call sp_start_job from your bash script to run the SQL Agent Job.
[sp_start_job (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Of course all of this depends on having the correct permissions, and there are many things that can complicate these steps, but this is the general outline.

Comment: Thanks, but It looks like I can't use the import wizard because I need automation this to operating every morning. Or can I?

Comment: The import wizard will generate a file that you can save.  You can then use SQL Server Agent to schedule the file to run every morning.

Answer (score 0):

is it about 2 tables on 2 different servers?

first, please make a query on IP 23, then select table A using Link Server to IP 22, then the results are entered into the temp table (# / @).
then insert the data in the temp table into table B.

Comment: Thanks but the question is how to insert data into table B?
I've select table A and put it on csv or txt file and view but how can I send it into table B in different server automatically every morning?
I've tried using sqlcmd but it not works for me.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.